# Angular datapicker sending too much data about a date and needs to be converted

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datepicker

With Angular 5, I'm using a some npm package for dates

```
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
```

Issue is that what I NEED to send to the server is

this format only

```
2018-05-23
```

However, it is sending all of this

```
Tue%20May%2022%202018%2017:00:00%20GMT-0700%20(US%20Mountain%20Standard%20Time)
```

Full service call

http://server:9080/RxPace/rest/config/users?eff-date=Tue%20May%2022%202018%2017:00:00%20GMT-0700%20(US%20Mountain%20Standard%20Time)

How can I convert that?

Comment: Can you please add some code around how you're getting that date, and how you're constructing your API call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

%20 is space URI-encoded (you see it everywhere, so it's a good thing to remember)
Which means we can just:

```
const str = decodeURIComponent("Tue%20May%2022%202018%2017:00:00%20GMT-0700%20(US%20Mountain%20Standard%20Time)");
// which gives: "Tue May 22 2018 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)";
```

And that looks like a valid date-string, so we can just pass it to Date...

```
new Date(str); // Note that this will return the date in YOUR locale.
// In my case: Wed May 23 2018 09:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time)
```

Since your required format is very similar to the toISOString-format, we'll just use that and split at the "T".

```
const myFormat = new Date(str).toISOString().split("T")[0];
// returns "2018-05-23" (or whatever your locale might be).
```

May need some error-checking. (Like if the date is valid or not).

For anything more advanced I'd just pull in [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/format)

Edit: (Oh, I guess my reading comprehensions skills are off as usual. Still, I think toISOString() and split is the easiest option (since it seems you already have a Date-object) without pulling other stuff in. Then there is https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/#locale-formats ...)

(Your problem is that you are trying to send a date-object instead of a string.)